# How to set fixed quantity of items in GridView Widget?

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-bitmap

I have GridView widget which is populated by 40 images taken from ArrayList, problem is when widget is trying to load more positions than 40 and it makes about few hundreds of blank cells with "loading" text. This wouldn't happen if number of items was fixed by 40, but how to do that?

[image]

This is my RemoteViewsFactory class:

```
public class WidgetRemoteViewsFactory implements RemoteViewsService.RemoteViewsFactory {
    private Context ctx;
    private Cursor cursor;
    private ArrayList<Bitmap> photos = new ArrayList<>(40);

    public WidgetRemoteViewsFactory(Context applicationContext, Intent intent) {
        ctx = applicationContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDataSetChanged() {

        String[] projection = new String[]{
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN,
                MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.MIME_TYPE
        };
        cursor = ctx.getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection, null,
                null, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 39; i++) {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(1));
            photos.add(bmp);
            cursor.moveToNext();
            Log.d(TAG, "loop iteration" + i );
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return cursor == null ? 0 : cursor.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getViewAt(int position) {
        if (position == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION ||
                cursor == null || !cursor.moveToPosition(position) || photos == null || photos.size() == 0 || position >= photos.size()) {
            return null;
        }
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_item);
            Bitmap img = resizeBitmapFitXY(250, 150, photos.get(position));
            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.imageView, img);
            return views;
    }

    @Override
    public RemoteViews getLoadingView() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return cursor.moveToPosition(position) ? cursor.getLong(0) : position;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }





    public Bitmap resizeBitmapFitXY(int width, int height, Bitmap bitmap){
        Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        float originalWidth = bitmap.getWidth(), originalHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(background);
        float scale, xTranslation = 0.0f, yTranslation = 0.0f;
        if (originalWidth > originalHeight) {
            scale = height/originalHeight;
            xTranslation = (width - originalWidth * scale)/2.0f;
        }
        else {
            scale = width / originalWidth;
            yTranslation = (height - originalHeight * scale)/2.0f;
        }
        Matrix transformation = new Matrix();
        transformation.postTranslate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
        transformation.preScale(scale, scale);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, transformation, paint);
        return background;
    }
}
```

Comment: Put your error logcat and line in which you got error.

Comment: please post your code. show us what you have tried

Comment: I have the feeling that you don't notify it's adapter

Comment: I've updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**you need to replace this code**

```
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 39; i++) {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(1));
            photos.add(bmp);
            cursor.moveToNext();
            Log.d(TAG, "loop iteration" + i );
        }
```

**and put this instead**

```
          if (cursor!=null && cursor.getCount()>0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(cursor.getString(1));
                    photos.add(bmp);
                    Log.d(TAG, "loop iteration" + i );
                }
            }
```

> the **problem** that you used a fixed size in the for loop `for (int i = 1; i <= 39; i++)`
>
> and the **solution** is to use `while()` loop to get all the item from the cursor and add it to your list

---

update answer after the comment :

> Q: if you decide in the loop to load only 40 and not to load the blank text

you must to do this

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 40;
    }
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't seems to work, widget remains an empty frame without any content, and in logcat I can see that there is more than 40 loop iterations. I wouldn't say that this loop is related to gridView issue because it's just populating array with photos and nothing more (imo). size of loop is fixed because this is exactly how many pictures I want to see im ny GridView, not all of them because if would load all pictures from my phone and there are thousands of them

Comment: the problem is that if statement in getViewAt, that empty cells are those nulls, which are "inflated" when conditions occurs

Comment: i updated the answer take a look at `getCount()` is that what you mean ?